# Gitlab CI pipeline does not run with workflow rule set

Tags: gitlab-ci, workflow, rules

Sorry for my rusty english...

I have this simple pipeline to test the `workflow` keyword with `rules`:

```yaml
image: docker:rc-dind

stages:
  - build-socle

workflow:
  rules:
    - changes:
        - "!/README.md"
      when: always

build-socle:
  stage: build-socle
  script:
    - echo "Lancement de la construction de l'image socle"
```

What i understand is that the pipeline should start for any modified files except `README.md`

i tried changing a file `myscript.sh' in the project, but the pipeline did not start...

Any suggestions why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    - changes:
        - "!/README.md"
```

Unfortunately, the `!` glob metacharacter is not supported in Ruby's `fnmatch`, therefore it is unsupported for use with `rules:changes:`. As mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges), you can only use [syntax supported by Ruby's fnmatch](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/File.html#method-c-fnmatch).

You can, however, formulate an equivalent negation without the use of the metacharacter:

```
rules:
  changes:
  - '**/{[^R]*,R,R[^E]*,RE,RE[^A]*,REA,REA[^D]*,READ,READ[^M]*,READM,READM[^E]*,README,README[^.]*,README.,README.[^m]*,README.m,README.m[^d]*,README.md?*}'
```

And this [should work as expected](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2A%2A%2F%7B%5B%5ER%5D%2A%2CR%2CR%5B%5EE%5D%2A%2CRE%2CRE%5B%5EA%5D%2A%2CREA%2CREA%5B%5ED%5D%2A%2CREAD%2CREAD%5B%5EM%5D%2A%2CREADM%2CREADM%5B%5EE%5D%2A%2CREADME%2CREADME%5B%5E.%5D%2A%2CREADME.%2CREADME.%5B%5Em%5D%2A%2CREADME.m%2CREADME.m%5B%5Ed%5D%2A%2CREADME.md%3F%2A%7D&matches=false&tests=not-readme.md&tests=README.md&tests=directory%2Ffoo%2Fnested%2Fanything.anything&tests=directory%2Fabc%2F&tests=foo%2Fbar%2FREADME.md) (with the caveat that files named `README.md` in other directories will also be ignored).