# run gitlab-ci pipeline if files outside a folder have changed

Tags: gitlab-ci

our project is organized in multiple directories, e.g.

```bash
$ tree 
.
├── README.md
├── docs
│   └── TUTORIAL1.md
└── src
    └── helloworld.c
```

The jobs for building the entire project take a while to finish, i would like to trigger unnecessary jobs.

Now, any changes to the `docs/` directory will never change the outcome of the CI (as this folder is simply not being "built" or tested).
So I would like to automatically skip jobs that only change files in that specific folder.

We have the `rules:changes` keyword, which I should be able to use for this task.
Unfortunately I completely failed so far.

The only thing I was able to concoct until now is this:

```yaml
ignore-changed-docs:
  rules:
    - changes:
      - "docs/*"
      when: never
    - changes:
      - "*"
      - "**/*"
      when: always
```

This should

- skip the job if only files in `docs/` have changed
- run the job if any files outside of `docs/` have changed

Unfortunately i also does

- skip the job if files both in `docs/` *and* outside of `docs/` have changed (since the `changes: docs/*` is triggered).

which is of course not what i want.

I want to skip jobs that *only* change files in the `docs/` folder.

Reverting the logic (e.g. **only** run jobs that change files in `src/`) is not an option: directories come and go and there are yet-unknown files outside of `doc/` that need building/testing.

So how can I automatically skip a job if it only contains changes in a given directory?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would use a glob pattern like `!docs/` but Ruby's fnmatch, which GitLab uses, doesn't support the `!` metacharacter.

However, you can formulate an equivalent for this without the need for the metacharacter. Admittedly, it is a bit verbose and odd-looking, but it works.

```yaml
rules:
  - changes:
      paths:
        # match files/directories in the root which are not "docs"
        - '{[^d]*,d,d[^o]*,do,do[^c]*,doc,doc[^s]*,docs?*}'
        # match changes in subdirs other than "docs"
        - '{[^d]*,d,d[^o]*,do,do[^c]*,doc,doc[^s]*,docs?*}/**/*'
```

There might be a way to make this work in one `paths:` pattern, but it wasn't immediately obvious to me.

Related:

- [Is there a way to create a Gitlab job CI rule that does not run the job when only if one file was updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178813/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-gitlab-job-ci-rule-that-does-not-run-the-job-when-onl)
- [Gitlab CI pipeline does not run with workflow rule set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75960390/gitlab-ci-pipeline-does-not-run-with-workflow-rule-set)
- [Is there a way to write a glob pattern that matches all files except those in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69905938/5747944)